# How to bind to Button BorderThickness?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have created a custom style in xaml, for the `Button` class. Here is the relevant part:

```
<Rectangle
    Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because while `StrokeThickness` is a `double`, `BorderThickness` is a `Thickness`.

How can I bind to the actual value of the thickness (which will always be uniform), without messing with converters?

Before you mark as an exact duplicate, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935416/how-bind-borderthickness-in-template) is different.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935416/how-bind-borderthickness-in-template... just kidding

Comment: @Rasa Sure, get me all excited with a response in my inbox :'( ... ;)

Comment: You have to go in for converter.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I'd like more substantiation for that claim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Rectangle
    Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    StrokeThickness="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
        Path=BorderThickness.Left}"/>
```

**Note**

The following binding

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=MyProperty}
```

is the same as

```
{TemplateBinding MyProperty}
```

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Eventually `{TemplateBinding BorderThickness.Left}` works too?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Con x:Key="abc" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="{Binding abc, Converter={StaticResource abc}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>


namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new { abc = new Thickness(4) };
        }
    }    

    public class Con : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((Thickness)value).Left;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, 
                                  Type targetType, 
                                  object parameter, 
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If no other options arise, I'll have to use a converter, but I'd like to try to do it without one first.